# Prove using $ \varepsilon-\delta $ that $ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac {x^2+2xy-3y^2}{x^2-y^2} = 2 $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Prove limit using $ \varepsilon-\delta $ definition that: $$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac
>  {x^2+2xy-3y^2}{x^2-y^2} = 2 $$

I've been reading quite a lot about how to prove limits; so I want to show what I've done so far in this one, so you can tell me any suggestion (tricks) and even point out any mistake.

**What I've tried:**

I want to find $ \delta $ for every $ \varepsilon $ that verifies: $$ 0 < \left \| (x,y) - (1,1) \right \| < \delta \Rightarrow \left | \frac {x^2+2xy-3y^2}{x^2-y^2} - 2 \right | < \varepsilon $$

So here is my attempt:

$$ \begin{align*}
\left | \frac {x^2+2xy-3y^2}{x^2-y^2} - 2 \right | &\overset{(1)}{=} \left | \frac {y-x}{y+x} \right | \\ 
 &\overset{(2)}{\leq} \frac {|x|+|y|}{|x+y|} \\ 
 &\overset{(3)}{\leq} \frac {2\left \| (x,y)-(1,1) \right \|}{|x+y|} \\
 &\overset{(4)}{\leq} 4\left \| (x,y)-(1,1) \right \| \\
 & < \ 4 \delta
\end{align*} $$

So I can take $ \delta = \varepsilon / 4 $. Is this right?

**Justifications:**

(1) Basic operations.

(2) Triangle inequality.

(3) I used $ |x| \leq \left \| (x,y)-(1,1) \right \| $.

(4) I supposed $ |x| < 1/2 $ and also $ |y| < 1/2 $ then $ |x+y| < 1/2 $. (I don't understand why this step holds though).

(5) The metric I'm using is: $ \left \| (x,y) \right \| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} $

Comment: What makes you believe that this equality is true?

Comment: I evaluated the limit and then I verified with Wolfram Alpha, is it wrong?

Comment: it is only 2 when you take the limit along the line $y=x$. The limit is equal to 1 if you approach along the x-axis, and 3 if you approach along the y-axis. Technically the limit doesn't exist because of this path dependence.

Comment: It is wrong. Use polar coordinates to see why.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I commited a typo, I corrected it now. It's $ (x,y) \to (1,1) $.

Comment: Re: *If you also can recommend me some links.* Maybe you can look at some questions tagged [limits+multivariable-calculus](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limits+multivariable-calculus).

Comment: If you use the triangular inequality like you did you end up with $\frac {|x|+|y|}{|x+y|}$ which is close to 1 as $x$ and $y$ converge to 1. What you need to do is minimize that.

Comment: Also the inequality in ($3$) is wrong. $ |x| \leq \left \| (x,y)-(1,1) \right \| $. The lhs is around $1$ but the rhs is around $0$.

Answer (score 3):

I always like to let
variables go to zero.
So,
if we let
$x = u+1$
and
$y = v+1$,

$\begin{array}\\
\frac {x^2+2xy-3y^2}{x^2-y^2}
&=\frac {(u+1)^2+2(u+1)(v+1)-3(v+1)^2}{(u+1)^2-(v+1)^2}\\
&=\frac {u^2+2u+1+2(uv+u+v+1)-3(v^2+2v+1)}{(u^2+2u+1)-(v^2+2v+1)}\\
&=\frac {u^2+4u+2uv-3v^2-4v)}{u^2+2u-v^2-2v}\\
&=\frac {u^2+2uv-3v^2+4u-4v}{u^2-v^2+2u-2v}\\
&=\frac {(u-v)(u+3v)+4(u-v)}{(u-v)(u+v)+2(u-v)}\\
&=\frac {(u+3v)+4}{(u+v)+2}
\quad\text{(for }u \ne v)\\
\end{array}
$

The limit is,
therefore,
$\lim_{u \to 0, v \to 0} \frac {(u+3v)+4}{(u+v)+2}
=\frac{4}{2}
=2
$.

In this case,
it was harder.

Comment: You are not using the $\delta-\epsilon$ argument like the question says

Comment: No he isn't but you don't need such an argument here to see the limit is 2. +1

Answer (score 2):

$x^2+2xy - 3y^2=(x+3y)(x-y), x^2-y^2 = (x-y)(x+y)\to L = \displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{x+3y}{x+y}$. The limit varies so it doesn't exist....

**Update**: Based on your recent edit, the new limit is $2$ since now $(x,y) \to (1,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac {x^2+2xy-3y^2}{x^2-y^2}$$
factorizing numerator and denominator we have,
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac {(x+3y)(x-y)}{(x+y)(x-y)}$$
$$\implies  \lim_{(x,y)\to(1,1)} \frac {x+3y}{x+y} $$
$$=\frac{4}{2}=2$$

Comment: The question requires a $\delta-\epsilon$ argument

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** As in many limit problems about fractions, factorize both the numerator and the denominator and cancel any identical terms. The denominator is the difference of two squares, so is easy to factor. The numerator is a trinomial and is not much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

First you factor out the $(x-y)$ term to get
$$
f(x,y) = \frac{x+3y}{x+y}.
$$
To simplify further let $x=u+1$ and $y=v+1$:
$$
g(u,v) = \frac{4+u+3v}{2+u+v}.
$$
and we look for the limit as $(u,v) \rightarrow (0,0)$.

Given $\epsilon\gt0 $ suppose $\|(u,v)\|\lt \epsilon$. We have $|u|\lt \epsilon$ and $|v|\lt \epsilon$ and we calculate
$$
|g(u,v)-2|=\frac{|v-u|}{|2+u+v|}
$$
The numerator is bounded above by $|u|+|v| \le 2 \epsilon$.

The denominator is bounded below by $2-|u|-|v| \gt 2-2 \epsilon \gt 1$ for $\epsilon \lt{1\over2}$

So the whole thing is bounded above by $2\epsilon$. This is your $\delta$.